# Site redirecting to a malicious website, already cleaned the code

Tags: web, malware

I have a website which is infected by some malicious malware. In the beginning I could notice that there was some strange javascript code on the site pages so I delete it and everything was fine for a few days, but now google lists the website as dangerous even though that I have checked the site code for any strange code but I could not find anything.

I have try [Sucuri SiteCheck](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/) and it detects redirections to a malicious site. At first I thought that it may be an .htaccess file that was doing the redirection but I checked the files on the shared server and there is no .htaccess file.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Try deleting all javascript, and then manually adding the javascript back in bit by bit (re-download all javascript libraries from source), and check all custom javascript carefully.

Comment: Disable JavaScript and see what happens. If it doesn't redirect with JS disabled, look for `location` or `window.location` in the source where it shouldn't be. Also maybe search for parts of the URL it's redirecting to, as that will likely be hard-coded in. Also, have you tried visiting the site on another computer? There's a chance your browser might have cached the redirect. What ronalchn said is more thorough and wouldn't miss encoded/obfuscated javascript, so that would be the next step.

Comment: When I enter the site I do not get redirected to any other site

Comment: So the question is just about Google's flag? See xxbbcc's answer.

Comment: I have already requested a review for the site, using google tools I get the following: >> Of the 36 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 2 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent. The last time Google visited this site was on 2012-09-01, and the last time suspicious content was found on this site was on 2012-08-29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting account has bee hacked. Change your password on your hosting service. Go through your site code once more (every file) and look for things that don't belong. Clear your browser cache and then try again. If your account is hacked again, find a new hosting service. Once you're sure that your site is clean and your account has been secured, let Google know about the problems and request a removal from their suspect list:

[Google support](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163633)

Comment: Already done that, also I checked my pc for any malware/keyloggers/virus/etc and it always come clean. It appears to me that my hosting service may have a security problem.

Comment: There are other things that can cause warnings to appear on the search results besides redirects. For example, having any links in the form `http://[ip address]/~[some account name]` can cause it (phishing sites often do not have domain names and so use this scheme). Is it just a flag on the results page, or does Google show that interim *site is malicious* page? Does every page for your site have the flag or just a few? Search `site:yourdomain.com` to check.

Comment: Also, in addition to changing your password on your hosting service, check your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server. If you don't use SSH, delete it; if you do, probably still delete it and key re-add your public keys. If someone hacked your account they could have added a password-less SSH key which would allow them to access your account regardless of how many times you change your password.

Comment: @aljndrrr If you did all that and you still have the problem, you should get rid of that hosting service. I had similar experience with some hosting services and you can't do much other than to move to a more respectable place. (Big providers can have this issue, too, so just because you may have an account with a big host it doesn't guarantee that it's secure.)

Answer (score 0):

check your .htaccess file for the redirection or the whether the files contain and unwanted malicious java script.